# Latex commands suddenly appearing in rmarkdown pdf

Tags: r, pdf, encoding, latex, r-markdown

Facing a very weird problem when knitting my rmarkdown document to a pdf...

Everything comes out nicely but halfway through the document, rmarkdown seems to not recognise the latex commands and decides to print them out directly in the pdf, leading to my pdf having latex commands like:

\begin{figure}[H]

and this affect the rest of the document.

I am not sure if its because of some encoding issues -- how does one check this and is there a solution to this?

Have been struggling with this for hours!

Would appreciate any advice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem finally! Its % sign in my figure caption!

Hope this might help anyone who is having trouble with latex.